# Error with IIS Server, Jet DataBase and client in Singapore

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, iis, odbc

I have a strange case with a client in Singapore.
I'm working in a big percentage by Americans (giving support to Latin America, South and North America).

I have a IIS Server and a Web Page created with ASP.Net (Framework 2.0)

I using an Excel file (Format 2003) that uploads into the Server and after that I try to read it with ODBC connection.

Everything works perfect since more than 3 years. But recently a client in Singapore shows the following error when the Web page try to read the Excel:

SOURCE >> Microsoft JET Database Engine

DESCRIPTION >> Selected collating sequence not supported by the operating system.

Any idea or hint about this problem?

As additional; also I have others costumers in Singapore using the same Web Page without problems

Comment: Are the working customers using exactly the same Excel spreadsheet or is everyone using their own spreadsheet. The first step in problem solving is narrowing it down to what is really causing the issue.

Comment: @ElectricLlama: It's the same Excel template for all users. Even if the user send me the Excel file, I can upload the file into the same Web Page without problem.

Comment: So every client reads exactly the same file via ODBC, but one client gets an error - please clarify if they are all reading the same single file or not.

Comment: @ElectricLlama: Yes, I tested the same excel file in different computers

Comment: So you have two users performing an operation on an identical file and one gets a collation error. What exactly is the operation? Is the ASP.Net page opening the Excel file through ODBC and displaying it to the user?

Comment: @ElectricLlama: The process after the ASP.Net uploads the file, I need to read the file with ODBC connection to get the information and create a SQL sentence to insert this data into a SQL Server.

Comment: Just to verify, can you get a the file from a working user, send that to your Singapore user and get them to upload it and verify?

Comment: @ElectricLlama: Yes, I tested this before. The same working file I sent to my client in Singapore and still doesn't works

Comment: Can you verify - is the file uploaded to the server, then it is opened via ODBC on the server and inserted, or is the file opened via ODBC on the client and transferred from the cilent? i.e. does it 1. Upload the file to the server then transfer from the server to the database or 2. Transfer from the client dorectly to the database? The thing is, the server shouldn't care what the client is, it should use all the settings from the server.